# Terraforming a managed instance of Airflow on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, airflow

I'm trying to create a managed instance of Airflow on Azure using Terraform. This is what I have:

```
terraform {
    required_version = "~> 1.3"

    required_providers {
        azurerm = {
            source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
            version = ">= 3.71, < 4.0"
        }

        azapi = {
            source  = "Azure/azapi"
            version = ">= 1.9.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "azapi" {
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-rg" {
    name     = "someresourcegroupname"
    location = "uksouth"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example-adf" {
    name                = "someadfexamplename"
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-rg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-rg.name
}

resource "azapi_resource" "example-adf_airflow" {
    type = "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01"
    name = "Airflow1"
    parent_id = azurerm_data_factory.example-adf.id
    schema_validation_enabled = false
    timeouts {}

    body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
            type = "Airflow"
            description = "Airflow integration runtime"
            typeProperties = {
                computeProperties = {
                    location = azurerm_data_factory.example-adf.location
                    enableAutoscale = false
                    enableAvailabilityZones = false
                    computeSize = "Small"
                    extraNodes = 0
                }
                airflowProperties = {
                    airflowRequirements = ["azure-cli==2.52.0"]
                    enableTriggerers = false
                    gitSyncProperties = {
                        branch = "main"
                        encryptedCredential = "encryptedCredentialGoHere"
                        gitCredentialType = "PAT"
                        gitServiceType = "Github"
                        repo = "https://github.com/repo/reponame.git"
                        username = "username"
                    }
                    airflowVersion = "2.4.3"
                    enableAADIntegration = true
                    airflowEntityReferences = []
                    encryptedSecrets = []
                    secrets = []
                    pythonVersion = "3.8"
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Terraform plan and apply works fine, and the resources are created in Azure, except for the Airflow runtime, which appears in the UI initially with a `Starting` status but around 20 minutes later, it will change to `Stopped` and give the following error:
[image: Airflow error]

Anyone got any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I Tried Terraforming a managed instance of Airflow on Azure I was able to provision the Airflow and I didn't face any issues as it works fine even after a reasonable amount of time.

The error code `AirflowDeploymentError` indicates an error deploying an Airflow workflow. The error message `InternalError` provides little detail and the trace correlation ID `9283f34d-05e6-4dd6-a622-af1a79ca3eae` can be used to track down more information about the error in the Airflow logs.

This was due to deployment issues in general, which can be sorted by redeploying the service with all the permissions relevant to the service.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
 provider "azapi" {
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-rg" {
    name     = "demorg-vk"
    location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example-adf" {
    name                = "someadfexamplevk"
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-rg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-rg.name
}

resource "azapi_resource" "example-adf_airflow" {
    type = "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01"
    name = "Airflow1"
    parent_id = azurerm_data_factory.example-adf.id
    schema_validation_enabled = false
    timeouts {}

    body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
            type = "Airflow"
            description = "Airflow integration runtime"
            typeProperties = {
                computeProperties = {
                    location = azurerm_data_factory.example-adf.location
                    enableAutoscale = false
                    enableAvailabilityZones = false
                    computeSize = "Small"
                    extraNodes = 0
                }
                airflowProperties = {
                    airflowRequirements = ["azure-cli==2.52.0"]
                    enableTriggerers = false
                    gitSyncProperties = {
                        branch = "main"
                        encryptedCredential = "encryptedCredentialGoHere"
                        gitCredentialType = "PAT"
                        gitServiceType = "Github"
                        repo = "https://github.com/repo/reponame.git"
                        username = "username"
                    }
                    airflowVersion = "2.4.3"
                    enableAADIntegration = true
                    airflowEntityReferences = []
                    encryptedSecrets = []
                    secrets = []
                    pythonVersion = "3.8"
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm also facing the same kind of error while deploying an adf-managed airflow instance using terraform. "ErrorDetails":"Airflow deployment timeout.
I'm using the same code you mentioned except with an existing resource group. data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing" {
  name = "terraform-k8s"
}
.Also, I'm using base64 encoding for encryptedCredential @Vinay